# Positioning elements on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down that is concealed by the image as shown in the following image. I want the drop down to be on the top of the image. How can I do that?

[image: Dropdown concealed by image part]

Is it done through  CSS?

Comment: I haven't yet deployed it...sorry..!!

Comment: You can copy+paste the relevant code into www.jsfiddle.net for us to have a look at.

Comment: @BhushanFirake its totally z-index game so please show us your code to understand how did u make this drop down than we will be able to tell you much better answer..........

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nashabhu/nNhXr/ here is my code..

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I have pasted my code in jsfiddle ...

Comment: @ShailenderArora:..PAsted the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by putting greater `z-index` to dropdown

> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

like

```
img{
  z-index:5;
}

.dropdown{
   z-index:6;
}
```

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:relative , position:absolute, or position:fixed).

```
.photo-thumb {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    z-index: 6;  <------- you have z-index 6 here 
}
```

and

```
.menu ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1F2024;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease 0.1s;

    z-index: 7; <-----this is the key try z-index 7 here 
}
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Don't forget the positioning.

Comment: @BhushanFirake than solution is also here too....see updated answer and fiddle...:)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks mai i ask why fiddle i have already added working fiddle ... ?????

Comment: I made it and there was already a solution. Just added it in for further reference instead of making a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to make it a background image of an element rather than an actual image tag